# Datatype creation in AWS DynamoDB and elastic search for List of URL's

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have enabled Aws DynamoDB streams and created a lambda function to index the data into Elasticsearch.

In my DynamoDb table there is a column named URL in this i am going to store the list of URL's for a single row.

URL is most preferably like object URL of AWS S3 objects

After streaming i am indexing the data into elastic search here my question is what is the datatype should i prefer to store multiple URL in both DynamoDB (single row) and Elasticsearch (Single document)

Could some one help me to achieve this in most efficient way? Thanks in advance

**Json structure**

```
 {
      "id":"234561",
      "policyholdername":"xxxxxx",
      "age":"24",
      "claimnumber":"234561",
      "policynumber":"456784",
      "url":"https://dgs-dms.s3.amazonaws.com/G-3114_Textract.pdf",
      "claimtype":"Accident",
      "modified_date":"2020-02-05T17:36:49.053Z",
      "dob":"2020-02-05T17:36:49.053Z",
      "client_address":"no,7 royal avenue thirumullaivoyal chennai"
    }
```

In future for a single claim number there should be multiple URL's
So, how to handle this?

Comment: can you give a json structure of how the URL is stored in dynamodb ?

Comment: Have provided the Json Structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Dynamo DB types. But in Elasticsearch there is no dedicated type for list. To store list of strings(URLs in your case) you can use keyword field type.

For example your data can be like

```
 {
      "id":"234561",
      "policyholdername":"xxxxxx",
      "age":"24",
      "claimnumber":"234561",
      "policynumber":"456784",
      "url":["https://dgs-dms.s3.amazonaws.com/G-3114_Textract.pdf","https://foo/bar/foo.pdf"]
      "claimtype":"Accident",
      "modified_date":"2020-02-05T17:36:49.053Z",
      "dob":"2020-02-05T17:36:49.053Z",
      "client_address":"no,7 royal avenue thirumullaivoyal chennai"
    }
```

and the equivalent elasticsearch mapping could be

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "url": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the search query can be

```
POST index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "url": "https://foo/bar/foo.pdf"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One of my technical team asked me to go with multi field approach, the mapping you have mentioned above is related to multifield approach?

Comment: Multi field is basically u can define a field as text as well as keyword. This depends on what kind of search you are going to do on the field.